# C : How to sort words from variable number of files with frequency # and in alphabetical order

Tags: c, sorting, command-line-arguments, word-frequency

I'm new to C and I'm having trouble writing a C program that takes a variable number of files via command line arguments and sorts the words by (ASCII)alphabetical order and prints only unique words, but includes the frequencies. I managed to get as far as sorting words through user input in alphabetical order, but I don't know how to properly write the code to take file input, and I also have no clue how to only print each unique word once with it's frequency.

here's what I got so far, which takes stdin rather than file and lacks frequency count:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
char a[2048][2048];
int i = 0, 
    j = 0, 
    k = 0, 
    n;

while(i < 2048 && fgets(a[i], 2048, stdin) != NULL)
{
    n = strlen(a[i]);
    if(n > 0 && a[i][n-1] == '\n')
    a[i][n -1] = '\0';
    i++;
}

for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    char max[2048];
    strcpy (max,a[j]);
    for(k = j + 1; k < i; k++)
    {
        if(strcmp(a[k], max) < 0)
        {
            char temp[2048];
            strcpy(temp, a[k]);
            strcpy(a[k], max);
            strcpy(max, temp);
        }
    }
    strcpy(a[j],max);
}

for( j = 0; j < i; j++){
    printf("%s\n", a[j]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Modify your main() to: `main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Then you can pass arguments to your program.

Comment: Have you learned about structures or dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` and `free()`) yet?  Your code is treating lines as 'words'.  That may be OK if in fact your file(s) do contain one word per line.  There are few words that are going to be anything like 2048 characters long; I'd be tempted to reduce the second dimension of the array to something like 256 or 128.  That said, what you've done is far better than what is often seen, where the second dimension might be just 20, or 10.

Comment: I don't know the scope of your assignment, but [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) are kind of nice when it comes to histogram-like or counting things like strings. Use the words as key and the count as the data. But if you want the words sorted then maybe some kind of tree structure instead?

Comment: As you are speaking of words, you should considere specifying what a word is in your context. And you should convert them to same case.

Answer (score 2):

In order to read words in a file into an array holding only unique words while keeping track of the number of occurrences of each time a word is seen, can be done in a couple of ways. An easy and straight-forward approach is to keep 2 separate arrays. The first, a 2D character array of sufficient size to hold the number of words anticipated, and the second, a numeric array (`unsigned int` or `size_t`) that contains the number of times each word is seen *at the same index* as the word is stored in the character array.

The only challenge while reading words from the file is to determine if a word has been *seen* before, if not, the new word is added to the `seen` character array at a given `index` and the frequency array `freq` is then updated at that index to reflect the word has been seen `1` time (e.g. `freq[index]++;`).
If while checking against your list of words in `seen`, you find the current word already appears at index `X`, then you skip adding the word to `seen` and simply update `freq[X]++;`.

Below is a short example that does just that. Give it a try and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXW 100
#define MAXC 32

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* initialize variables & open file or stdin for reading */
    char seen[MAXW][MAXC] = {{ 0 }};
    char word[MAXC] = {0};
    size_t freq[MAXW] = {0};
    size_t i, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* seen 1st word into 'seen' array, update index 'idx' */
    if (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word) == 1) {
        strcpy (seen[idx], word);
        freq[idx]++;
        idx++;
    }
    else {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file read error.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each word in file */
    while (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word) == 1) {
        /* check against all words in seen */
        for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
            /* if word already in 'seen', update 'freq' count */
            if (strcmp (seen[i], word) == 0) {
                freq[i]++;
                goto skipdup;   /* skip adding word to 'seen' */
            }
        } /* add word to 'seen', update freq & 'idx' */
        strcpy (seen[idx], word);
        freq[idx]++;
        idx++;

    skipdup:

        if (idx == MAXW) { /* check 'idx' against MAXW */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXW words exceeded.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    printf ("\nthe occurrence of words are:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf ("  %-28s : %zu\n", seen[i], freq[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/file_words_occur file_words_occur.c
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/words.txt
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. the fox jumps over the dog to avoid the squirrel.
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/file_words_occur <dat/words.txt

the occurrence of words are:

  the                          : 8
  quick                        : 1
  brown                        : 1
  fox                          : 2
  jumps                        : 2
  over                         : 2
  lazy                         : 1
  dog                          : 2
  to                           : 1
  avoid                        : 1
  squirrel                     : 2
  was                          : 1
  in                           : 1
  path                         : 1
  of                           : 1
  captain                      : 1
  jack                         : 1
  sparrow                      : 1
  a                            : 1
  pirate                       : 1
  so                           : 1
  brave                        : 1
  on                           : 1
  seven                        : 1
  seas                         : 1
```

**Note:** the longest word in the abridged dictionaries is `28` chars long (*Antidisestablishmentarianism*). It requires space for the nul-terminating character for a total of `29` chars. The choice of `MAXC` of `32` should accommodate all normal words.

---

**Handle Multiple Files + Sorting Words/Occurrences Alphabetically**

As noted in the comments, handling multiple files can be done with the existing code, simply by utilizing the codes ability to read from `stdin`. All you need to do is `cat file1 file2 file3 | ./prog_name`. Updating the code to handle multiple files as arguments is not difficult either. (you could just wrap the existing body with a `for (j = 1, j < argc, j++)` and open/close each filename provided. (some other slight tweaks to the `fp` declaration are also needed)

But what's the fun in that? Whenever you think about doing the same thing more than once in your program, the *"I should make that a function"* lightbulb should wink on. That is the proper way to think about handling repetitive processes in your code. (arguably, since there is just one thing we are doing more than once, and since we could simply wrap that in a `for` loop, we could get by without a function in this case -- but where is the learning in that?)

OK, so we know we are going to move the file-read/frequency-count code to a function, but what about the sort requirement? That's where we need to change the data handling from 2-arrays to an *array of struct*. Why go from 2-arrays to handling the data in a struct?

When you sort the words alphabetically, you must maintain the relationship between the `seen` array and the `freq` array so after the sort, you have the right number of occurrences with the right word. You cannot independently sort the arrays and keep that relationship. However, if we put both the *word* and the *occurrences* of that word in a struct, then we could sort an array of structs by the *word* and the right number of occurrences remains associated with the right word. e.g. something like the following would work:

```
typedef struct {
    char seen[MAXC];
    size_t freq;
} wfstruct;
```

(`wfstruct` is just a semi-descriptive name for *word-frequency struct*, it can be anything that makes sense to you)

Which in your program you will declare as an array of with something like:

```
    wfstruct words[MAXW];
```

(you will actually want to initialize each member to zero -- that is done in the actual code below)

How to sort an array of that? `qsort` is your friend. `qsort` will sort a collection of anything so long as you can pass `qsort` (1) the array, (2) how many elements to sort, (3) the size of the elements, and (4) a compare function that takes a `const void` pointer to the elements it will compare. This always gives new C programmers fits because you have to figure out (a) how to pass the element of your *array-of-whatever* as a pointer, and (b) then how to handle getting the data you need back out of the pointer in the function to compare.

The declaration for a comparison function for `qsort` is:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b);
```

To write the compare function, all you need to ask yourself is *"What do I need to compare to sort my collection the way I want it sorted?"* In this case you know you want to sort the array of structs by the word `seen` in each element of the array of `wfstruct`. You know `seen` will be a simple character string, so you can sort using `strcmp`.

Then the final thing you need to ask yourself is *"How in the heck do I get my `seen` string out of `const void *a` (and `*b`) so I can feed it to `strcmp`?"* Here you know the `const void *a` must represent the basic element of what you will be sorting, which is `struct wfstruct`. So you know that `const void *a` is a pointer to `wfstruct`. Since it will be a pointer, you know you must use the `->` operator to derefernce the `seen` member of the struct. (e.g. the `seen` member is access as `mystruct->seen`.

But *"what is the rule regarding dereferncing a void pointer?"* (Answer: *"you can't derefernce a void pointer"*) How do you handle this? Simple, you just declare a pointer of type `struct wfstruct` in your `compare` function and *typecase* `a` to `(wfstruct *)`. Example:

```
    wfstruct *ap = (wfstruct *)a;
```

Now you have a *good-ole* `pointer to struct wfstruct` (or simply `pointer to wfstruct` since we included the `typedef` for `wfstruct` in its declaration). You do the same thing for `b` and now you can pass `ap->seen` and `bp->seen` to `strcmp` and sort your array of struct:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    wfstruct *ap = (wfstruct *)a;
    wfstruct *bp = (wfstruct *)b;
    return (strcmp (ap->seen, bp->seen));
}
```

The call to `qsort` in your program is nothing more than:

```
    /* sort words alphabetically */
    qsort (words, idx, sizeof *words, compare);
```

With the basics out of the way, you can now move the needed code to a function to allow you to read multiple files as arguments, keep a total of the number of words seen between files (as well as their frequency) and then sort the resulting array of structs alphabetically.

**note:** to keep track of the total number of words between multiple files (calls to your funciton), you can either return the number of words gathered for each file as the return from your read function, and keep a total that way, or you can simply pass a pointer to your total to the read function and have it updated directly in the function. We will take the second approach below.

Putting the pieces together, you get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXW 100
#define MAXC 32

typedef struct {
    char seen[MAXC];
    size_t freq;
} wfstruct;

int get_word_freq (wfstruct *words, size_t *idx, FILE *fp);
int compare (const void *a, const void *b);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* initialize variables & open file or stdin for seening */
    wfstruct words[MAXW] = {{{ 0 }, 0}};
    size_t i, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 2) { /* read from stdin */
        get_word_freq (words, &idx, stdin);
    }
    else {
        /* read each file given on command line */
        for (i = 1; i < (size_t)argc; i++)
        {   /* open file for reading */
            if (!(fp = fopen (argv[i], "r"))) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", 
                        argv[i]);
                continue;
            }

            /* check 'idx' against MAXW */
            if (idx == MAXW) break;

            get_word_freq (words, &idx, fp);
        }
    }

    /* sort words alphabetically */
    qsort (words, idx, sizeof *words, compare);

    printf ("\nthe occurrence of words are:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf ("  %-28s : %zu\n", words[i].seen, words[i].freq);

    return 0;
}

int get_word_freq (wfstruct *words, size_t *idx, FILE *fp)
{
    char word[MAXC] = {0};
    size_t i;

    /* read 1st word into array, update index 'idx' */
    if (*idx == 0) {
        if (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word) == 1) {
            strcpy (words[*idx].seen, word);
            words[*idx].freq++;
            (*idx)++;
        }
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: file read error.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* read each word in file */
    while (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word) == 1) {
        /* check against all words in struct */
        for (i = 0; i < *idx; i++) {
            /* if word already 'seen', update 'words[i]. freq' count */
            if (strcmp (words[i].seen, word) == 0) {
                words[i].freq++;
                goto skipdup;   /* skip adding word to 'words[i].seen' */
            }
        } /* add to 'words[*idx].seen', update words[*idx].freq & '*idx' */
        strcpy (words[*idx].seen, word);
        words[*idx].freq++;
        (*idx)++;

    skipdup:

        if (*idx == MAXW) { /* check 'idx' against MAXW */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXW words exceeded.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}

/* qsort compare funciton */
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    wfstruct *ap = (wfstruct *)a;
    wfstruct *bp = (wfstruct *)b;
    return (strcmp (ap->seen, bp->seen));
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/file_words_occur_multi dat/words.txt dat/words.txt

the occurrence of words are:

  a                            : 2
  avoid                        : 2
  brave                        : 2
  brown                        : 2
  captain                      : 2
  dog                          : 4
  fox                          : 4
  in                           : 2
  jack                         : 2
  jumps                        : 4
  lazy                         : 2
  of                           : 2
  on                           : 2
  over                         : 4
  path                         : 2
  pirate                       : 2
  quick                        : 2
  seas                         : 2
  seven                        : 2
  so                           : 2
  sparrow                      : 2
  squirrel                     : 4
  the                          : 16
  to                           : 2
  was                          : 2
```

---

**Passing Index (`idx`) as Non-Pointer**

As mentioned above, there are two ways to keep track of the number of unique words seen across multiple files: (1) pass the index and keep the total in `main`, or (2) pass a pointer to the index and update its value directly in the function. The example above passes a pointer. Since the additional syntax required to dereference and properly use the pointer value can be challenging for those new to C, here is an example of passing `idx` as a simple variable and keeping track of the total in `main`.

(**note:** you are required to pass the index either way, it's your choice whether you pass `idx` as a regular variable and work with a copy of the variable in the function, or whether you pass `idx` as a pointer and operate on the value directly in the function)

Here are the simple changes to `get_word_freq` and the changes required in `main` follow (note: `size_t` is chosen as the type rather than `int` because the array index can never be *negative*):

```
size_t get_word_freq (wfstruct *words, size_t idx, FILE *fp)
{
    char word[MAXC] = {0};
    size_t i;

    /* read 1st word into array, update index 'idx' */
    if (idx == 0) {
        if (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word) == 1) {
            strcpy (words[idx].seen, word);
            words[idx].freq++;
            idx++;
        }
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: file read error.\n");
            return idx;
        }
    }

    /* read each word in file */
    while (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word) == 1) {
        /* check against all words in struct */
        for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
            /* if word already 'seen', update 'words[i]. freq' count */
            if (strcmp (words[i].seen, word) == 0) {
                words[i].freq++;
                goto skipdup;   /* skip adding word to 'words[i].seen' */
            }
        } /* add to 'words[*idx].seen', update words[*idx].freq & '*idx' */
        strcpy (words[idx].seen, word);
        words[idx].freq++;
        idx++;

    skipdup:

        if (idx == MAXW) { /* check 'idx' against MAXW */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXW words exceeded.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);

    return idx;
}
```

The changes required in `main`:

```
    ...
    if (argc < 2) { /* read from stdin */
        idx = get_word_freq (words, idx, stdin);
    }
    else {
        /* read each file given on command line */
        for (i = 1; i < (size_t)argc; i++)
        {   /* open file for reading */
            ...
            /* check 'idx' against MAXW */
            if ((idx = get_word_freq (words, idx, fp)) == MAXW)
                break;
        }
    }
    ...
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I keep trying to run this, but if I include dat it says the directory doesn't exist. But if I only use cat it only shows the contents of the file.

Comment: OHH!!! `dat` is just a subdirectory I keep all my data files in so they don't clog up my source directory (there is over one thousand). I added my compile string to show you how I compile. I have a `bin` directory where all my compiled executables go for the same reason. If you have everything in one directory, then by all means just remove all the path info from the executable and data file, e.g.: `$ ./file_words_occur <words.txt` (without redirection just `$ ./file_words_occur words.txt`

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work with files I've made. My main trouble now is sorting the output in ASCII order as the program I posted does. When I try to add in the code fragment that arranges the order from my posted program, even after tweaking around the loop that prints the output, I still only get the output from your program.

Comment: Also, after more tweaking, I can't alter the program so that multiple files can be read from the command line.  For example I put in
./main /Users/colinsantos/Desktop/fname\ 2.txt /Users/colinsantos/Desktop/fname.txt
but I only get results for fname 2 . Is that a problem with my terminal input or is it a problem with the code.

Comment: Oh, yes, it only attempts to open one file given as an argument to the program. Having it read all is relatively trivial. Just loop over each argument and attempt to open it. (e.g. `for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) { .. FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[i], "r") : stdin; ... whole program ...}`. Use `qsort` to sort the words (however, you must coordinate that with the `freq` array - so we will just throw both in a `struct`). I'll have a bit of time in a couple of hours. If you haven't solved it, I'll post an update.

Comment: If you want to read multiple file as is, simply use `cat file1 file2 file3 file4 | ./prog_name`. That will work for as many files as you like. I'll work on an update in a bit.

Comment: Thanks, the command worked for me. I was watching videos and looking up how to use struct and linked lists, but I'm still stuck on how use them in my program.

Comment: Big edit added for handling multiple files as arguments, storing words/frequency as an array of `struct`, and sorting results alphabetically. You do not need/want a linked list here. Start with a statically declared array of struct. When you need to read an unlimited number, then we will dynamically allocate the array of struct, and `realloc` as needed. Let's get you walking with simple data structures before you complicate things with lists, etc. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks again, you've been a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are still many things to add to your program!

1. Loop over input files given on command line. A simple C way could be:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       FILE *fd;
       ...
       while (*(argv++) != NULL) {
           if strcmp(*argv, "-") { /* allow - to stand for stdin */
               fd = stdin;
           }
           else {
               fd = fopen(*argv, "r");
               if (fd == NULL) {
                   /* process error condition */
                   ...
                }
           /* process file */
           ...
           if (fd != stdin) fclose(fd); /* don't forget to close */
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Split the files in words

   ```
   char word[64];
   int cr;
   while ((cr = fscanf(fd, "%63s", word)) == 1) {
       filter(word); /* optionally convert to lower case, remove punctuation... */
       /* process word */
       ...
   }
   ```
3. store the words in a container and count their occurence. At the simplest level, you can use an array with linear search, but a tree would be much better.

   ```
   unsigned int maxWord = 2048, totWord = 0, nWord = 0;
   typedef {
       char *word;
       int count;
   } stat;
   stat * st = calloc(maxWord, sizeof(stat));
   ```

   and later

   ```
   void add(stat *st, const char * word) {
       unsigned int i;
       totWord += 1;
       for (i=0; i<nWord; i++) {
           if (strcmp(word, st[i].word) == 0) {
               st[i].count += 1;
               return;
           }
       }
       if (nWord < maxWord) {
           st[nWord].word = strdup(word);
           st[nWord].count += 1;
           nWord += 1;
       }
   }
   ```

You now have to glue above together, sort the `st` array (with `qsort`), and the frequency of each word is `((float) st[i].count) / totWord`